# MongoDB how to query a collection with array inside php

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

How can I query a MongoDB with array inside.

```
[{
    "issuer":"34a8c528-11f9-490c-82ef-db94808ba4d8",
    "dateAdded":1520547942137,
    "duration":2147483647,
    "reason":".",
    "active":false,
    "rank":"5569543b-efc4-4acf-b6b2-cafd3663b806",
    "rankName":"Owner"
},{
    "issuer":"34a8c528-11f9-490c-82ef-db94808ba4d8",
    "dateAdded":1520556569443,
    "duration":2147483647,
    "reason":".",
    "active":true,
    "rank":"5569543b-efc4-4acf-b6b2-cafd3663b806",
    "rankName":"Owner"
}]
```

I tried doing:

```
$result = $collection->find(array("groups.rankName" => "Owner"));
```

But it returns nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How about `$result = $collection->find(array("rankName" => "Owner"));`?
By adding `groups` you're actively searching for an object with that, although I understand that you meant the whole objects containing your `rankName` property.

Comment: Its stored on the group column